# show last message bottom of the page in AngularJS not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to show last message bottom of the page after open page using angularjs. or when send message show message on bottom.Basically, I am displaying messages on bottom of the page and I want to focus the last message.how to apply on section and span in html tags.

```
 <section class="chats" id="autoscroll">
     <span ng-repeat="message in messages | orderBy:'dateCreated'">
         <span ng-show="!message.notification">
             <p class="username" ng-show="!messageIsMine(message.username)">{{message.username}}</p>
             <div ng-class='getBubbleClass(message.username)'>
                 <p ng-bind="message.message"></p>
             </div>
             <div class="clear"></div>
         </span>
     </span>
 </section>
```

my js is

```
var messagegroupby = Firebase.get('groupChat','groupname'$stateParams.chatId);
messagegroupby.$loaded().then(function() {
    $scope.messages = messagegroupby;
    //$scope.messagesLength = messagegroupby.length;
    $timeout(function () {
        var scroller = document.getElementById("autoscroll");
        scroller.scrollTop = scroller.scrollHeight;
    }, 0, false);
});
```

Comment: Can you upload working file in snippet

Comment: this is short code Snippet above i mention

Comment: we need a working demo.

Comment: Image enough for this.. lot of code depending on this,,,

Comment: attach image and required css too

Comment: section.chats div {
  max-width: 255px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
section.chats p{
  margin: 0;
}
section.chats p.username{
  max-width: 255px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/w6yo1jyr/ see this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this

```
 var messagegroupby =        
 Firebase.get('groupChat','groupname'$stateParams.chatId);

  messagegroupby.$loaded().then(function() {
    $scope.messages = messagegroupby;
    //$scope.messagesLength = messagegroupby.length;
    $timeout(function () {
      window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    }, 0, false);
});
```